# how to copy just the text of an org heading?

Tags: org-mode, evil-mode

I'm on doom emacs (evil) - what's the best approach to copying the text of a heading? is there a text object? is there a way to define one? I know there's some org elements interface, but I don't know how to utilize it. If there's any prior work on this, I'd love a reference.
Cheers!